# SilverStripe: Sorting DataObject with has_many relation

Tags: silverstripe

In SilverStripe I have a event dataobject

```
class Event extends DataObject {
    private static $db = array(
        'Name'          => 'Text'
    );

    private static $has_many = array(
        'EventDates'    => 'EventDate'
```

that has many event dates:

```
class EventDate extends DataObject {
    private static $db = array(
        'Day'          => 'Date',
        'StartTime'     => 'Varchar',
        'EndTime'       => 'Varchar'    
    );
```

Now if I query all events on a page like

```
Event::get()
```

I want them to be sorted by the earliest date.

Which way is the best to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can define a static property on the DataObject class with a default sort rule:

```
<?php

  class EventDate extends DataObject {

    …
    // This also effects the default sorting of `has_many` related Events.
    private static $default_sort = "\"Day\" ASC";

  }

?>
```

Now

```
<?php

  // first we pick a Event object, for instance by a (given) $id
  $event = Event::get()->byId($id);
  // because the default sort ist Day the attached `EventDate` will now be sorted by `Day` if you don't specify otherwise
  $events = $event->EventDates();
  // will return the earliest Event (of course you don't filter events here which are in the past).
  $firstEvent = $events->First();

  // if you then want to sort differently at some place, you can call ->sort() on the list:
  $event = Event::get()->byId($id);
  $events = $event->EventDates()->sort('LastEdited', 'DESC');
  $lastEditedEvent = $events->First();

?>
```

Comment: But the Event class doesn't have a Day property!? When I insert the default_sort 'Day' I get "Unknown column 'Date' in 'field list'"

Comment: Yes, I accidently mixed up `Event` and `EventDate` (is corrected). Anyway the approach stays the same; you define a `$default_sort` on the DataObject model you want to get sorted by a specific rule.

Comment: So the default_sort=Day sorts the EventDates, that I know. But I want to sort the Events by their starting date, which is the earliest date among the many EventDates each one can have. Do I need a complicated join-query, or is there a better, more standard compliant way in SilverStripe?

Comment: Yes, this would lead to use of aggregation functions which are not fully supported by the orm. I recommend to take a look at http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/sqlquery to see how to handle customized/raw sql queries in SilverStripe.